# Exec Stored Procedure - Invalid Operator

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am running this:

```
exec create_quarter @quarter='4q10',@debug='0'
```

and I get this message:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Procedure create_quarter, Line 234
>   Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator.

```
@quarter is a CHAR(4)
```

What do I have to do to this statement:

```
SET @prev_quarter =  CASE WHEN LEFT(@quarter, 1) = '1' THEN '4Q' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(RIGHT(@quarter, 2) - 1 AS VARCHAR), 2)
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, LEFT(@quarter, 1) - 1) + RIGHT(@quarter, 3)
    END
```

to fix my issue?

Answer (score 3):

```
RIGHT(@quarter, 2) - 1
```

should be something like

```
CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(@quarter, 2)) - 1
```

and

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, LEFT(@quarter, 1) - 1)
```

should be something like

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, LEFT(@quarter, 1)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This `RIGHT(@quarter, 2) - 1` and this `LEFT(@quarter, 1) - 1` don't make sense.  How do you subtract 1 from a string?

Maybe you want to surround those in `cast(x as integer)`?

Answer (score 0):

These 2 parts are wrong:

```
RIGHT(@quarter, 2) - 1
```

AND

```
LEFT(@quarter, 1) - 1
```

`RIGHT` and `LEFT` will both return a string. You cannot subtract a number from a string.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!